# Reset page scale dynamically on iOs devices using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, scale

I want to dynamically reset zoom or scale in my Javascript app when it is open.
Let's say that the start page is zoomed in but when I open my app in a new dialog I want zoom to be reset.

I've tried dynamically changing the meta tags which works for android but fails On iOS. 
Is there any other trick.

Below is my function where I tried everything possible.

```
function setMeta(){


  $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, user-scalable=0');
    document.body.style.zoom="100%";

document.getElementById("medView").setAttribute('content','user-scalable=no, width=device-width, minimum-scale = 1, maximum-scale = 1');

      if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
        var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
        if (viewportmeta) {
            alert("we are here");
            viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0';
            document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () {
                viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6';
            }, false);
        }
    }

    }
```